# Azure Scheduler Implementation

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-scheduler

I have written a web job which will do multiple tasks that run on different schedules like once a day, once in every hour and so and I achieved this by using Timer delegate. Now I am thinking of changing that approach and create a Scheduler job for each scenario. I was able to find some information regarding schedules from googling but was never able to join them to form a flow.

I learned that we can create job collection and each collection can have 'n' jobs based on the pricing tier we are using. After creating a job the program logic that the job must do how can we bind them to the corresponding job?

Also linking jobs to job collection how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A typical workflow is that you would write to a Azure Message Queue with a message, then you would have an Azure Cloud Service that reads from that and does the processing.

To tie specific jobs to specific program logic you can either embed information about the type into the message and have something that generically picks the messages up and turns them into specific operations/classes or you could have behavior specific queues and each job would write to its own queue and you would read from each queue by a different Cloud Service.

Comment: You should use a webapp with a webjob rather than a cloud service in general

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve my problem either using API calls or queue processing

[Solution](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shakti5385/windows-azure-scheduler/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have a WebJob that has multiple methods, each of which needs to be called on a different schedule. Instead of going through the hassle of setting up a Scheduler and having yet another resource that you have to manage, mark each method you need called with a [TimerTriggerAttribute](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#user-content-timertrigger).

Comment: Thanks Rob , i will take a look at it :)